Batch inserting rows into new table is slow
I have two tables that hold user information. Table A has about 7 million rows, and table B has zero. Both have an index on user_id.  My goal is to insert a row in table B that contains a few of the already existing fields in table A, and I am seeing some unexpected performance challenges when batching the process.
Right now, I am using this code:
with toInsert as (
    select a.user_id, a.created_at, a.registered_date
    from a
    left outer join b using (user_id)
    where b.user_id is null
    limit 50
)
insert into b (user_id, created_at, registered_date)
select user_id, created_at, registered_date
from toInsert
returning *;

However this takes about 3 minutes to run after table B starts growing, while I'd expect that to be much faster.  The query plan indicates that it is doing index scans on both tables, and then a merge join on that result
Here is the query plan I'm seeing
Insert on b  (cost=0.86..53.58 rows=50 width=48)
 ->  Subquery Scan on toinsert  (cost=0.86..53.58 rows=50 width=48)
    ->  Limit  (cost=0.86..53.33 rows=50 width=32)
      ->  Merge Anti Join  (cost=0.86..6222611.33 rows=5929090 width=32)
            Merge Cond: (a.user_id = b_1.user_id)
            ->  Index Scan using a_pkey on a  (cost=0.43..6189771.44 rows=6460394 width=32)
            ->  Index Only Scan using b_pkey on b b_1  (cost=0.42..10047.61 rows=531304 width=16)

Is there a way to speed up the query?  Why do the indexes perform so poorly? I've also tried where not in instead of a left join, which was slightly faster, somehow, and was still doing a full table scan for each batch.

Please explain your rationale behind LIMIT 50 without ORDER BY. Source rows are picked arbitrarily. Is that intended? Picking new rows gets increasingly more expensive this way. If there can be concurrent writes, the query is still not safe against unique violations. Do you insert all rows from table A eventually? And always declare your version of Postgres, please.

@ErwinBrandstetter   This is PG 16 and yes, eventually all rows from A are inserted into B.   I added the order by and it is light speed now, thanks for the suggestion.  Looks like it replaces an index merge with a nested loop, would love to hear any elaboration of why this change makes this difference.

I am still confused about your objective. To copy the whole table, there are much faster ways.

Why is this a problem? It’s slow by design. Select all data you need in a single query and you’re done in a few seconds.

The actual situation is a little more complicated, and I reduced it down to where the issue seemed to be.  Still curious about how the order by makes a different, if you'd be so kind to share.

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) on both queries will show you why. If you need help, add the output to the question.

At first query looks OK. It takes first 50 rows that are in table a, but not in b, and inserts them. Issue is that when you have like 5 mln rows in both tables... It must iterate over one table and check other. Index can be used, since it is smaller, even index only scan is used, but at the end of the day - 5 mln rows must be somehow visited.
It should go faster:
https://www.depesz.com/2007/07/05/how-to-insert-data-to-database-as-fast-as-possible/
Old post showing that mln rows can be inserted in seconds.
So how? Maybe:
CREATE TABLE b AS (SELECT a.user_id, a.created_at, a.registered_date FROM a);? table is quite big, transaction can be a bit longer, it acquires read lock on rows in table a, but... should work.
To fix initial insert - maybe iterate over user_ids? If that is integer - just use between. Since that are ids we can assume they are not changing, so order + limit / offset can work as well. In short - try to do whole job without touching table b. Maybe at the end to ensure that everything is in place. But that is only one scan instead of scan per every 50 rows...
